# Need regex pattern to match MS Project predecessor list

Tags: regex, ms-project

In MS Project, tasks can be linked to multiple other tasks which can reside in separate (external) project files. The only way to get a reference to these externally linked tasks is to parse out the "Predecessors" field which is a comma-separated list of links. Unfortunately, those external links can have commas in the paths, so a simple split doesn't work.

Here is an example with 3 links, the second is external:

> 123FS+5d,\\server\folder, with commas\project1.mpp\456,789

For internal links, the format can be any of the following:

- 
- #tk
- #tk+#d
- #tk-#d

Where the first number is the ID, the placeholder tk can be FS, FF, SS, or SF, and the optional last part (the lag) is +/- # days.

For external links, the link information is preceded by the file name including the path, followed by a backslash. The path may be UNC (e.g. \\) or a mapped drive letter (e.g. L:\).

There can be one or more links in a field and all, some, or none can be external.

**I need a regex pattern to match these lists of links.**

Thank you for the assistance!

**EDIT**

For posterity's sake, here's the pattern that works best as it also matches paths from Project Server ("<>\file name\123")

```
(((<>\\[^\\]+\\)+)|([A-Z]:|\\)\\([^\\]+\\)+)?\d+([FS]{2}([+-]\d+d)?)?(?=,|$)
```

Also see [How can I get the Unique ID of an External Dependency Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68943247/ms-project-how-can-i-get-the-unique-id-of-an-external-dependency-task/68943829#68943829) for further enhancement on this regex pattern.

Comment: not sure what you're using to parse these things (and thus whether it might or might not support all the potentially useful "regex" features out there), but splitting will be a little harder (more complex) than simply identifying the links based upon your analysis of the possible patterns - working on MATCHING that pattern right now -- (what product/parser/language are you using to execute the regex)?

Comment: Also - do you need the path to the file name? or just the id numbers? the id numbers with the lag? etc...

Comment: @CodeJockey I'm using the MS VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 library in a VB6 project. I do need the full path... and I fixed the unc path example (the slash got escaped).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Initial Answer:

Using a modified version of the sample you provided and putting in a bunch of other things, I came up with this expression:

```
,(?=(([A-Z]:|\\)\\([^\\]+\\)+)?\d+([FS]{2}([+-]\d+d)?)?(?=,|$))
```

It identifies a comma that is followed by one of your possible patterns, and you SHOULD be able to use it to split your stuff out (I think) - let me know if you have problems and I'll try to help - running off to a meeting right now :-D

### EDIT:

To match the links themselves, rather than splitting, remove the initial comma and lookahead from the expression, like so (this is often the case for converting split expressions to match expressions, but not always...):

```
(([A-Z]:|\\)\\([^\\]+\\)+)?\d+([FS]{2}([+-]\d+d)?)?(?=,|$)
```

Comment: This is finding the commas that are the delimiters between the links and I can use that information to parse the string... but is there a way to get the match collection to give me the three parts directly?

Comment: @RachelHettinger as you asked for a regex to split, it has to match the commas.

Comment: ok - added the match expression after the split expression, though I would think VB supports both (???) -- now, do you need the entire link (e.g. `'\\server\path\file.mpp\334'` or `'123FF-223345d'`), or do you need the individual parts broken out as well (e.g. `'123FF-223345d'` --> `'123','FF','-223345'`, etc...)? the given expression should provide the former, and the latter should not be too hard to get from there if you are at all proficient with regex.

Comment: @CodeJockey  I've tried it on a few variations and it works great. The only one it's not picking up is an external file name without a path... but I'm not sure my data will have that. Thank you! (Sorry for the confusion over split vs. match...)

Comment: Hmm. So it doesn't handle drive-letter mappings all that well. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: @RachelHettinger The problem is ambiguity. In this variant `([^\\]+\\)+` eats up all characters, including the second link starting with `C:`. But there are basic problems `\\server\1,file\2` may be interpreted as one or two links. Two distinguish one has to use the `.mpp` ending that files must have. I'll give it a try...

Comment: If I had to pick, I would chose to not handle drive-letter mappings rather than relying on the .mpp extension... I think projects stored in MS Project Server will not have that extension :(

Comment: to pass on drive letters doesn't help with `\\server\folder\file\1,file\2` which would still be matched as one link.

Comment: @Arne, that's true, it won't work for a file without a path, but I've looked at several scenarios and can't find that situation--the link always includes the path. (I'll update the question to remove that criteria.) Thanks so much for your assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Your asked for split, but matching is easier and requires less features from your regex library:

```
((?:(?:\\\\|[A-Z]:).*\\)?\d+(?:(?:FS|FF|SS|SF)(?:\+|-)?(?:\d+d)?)?)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input while I was gone :) -- Your expression does not correctly parse a case where a server, path, or filename begins with a number, like `\\server\path\12 main street project.mpp\334`, but instead matches `\\server\path\12` and `334` -- I'm pretty sure that could happen in the wild... (??)

Comment: @CodeJockey thanks for the hint, I removed the reluctant quantifier for the folder characters to fix it...bad idea, does eat up other links... hmm. Have to think about it.

Comment: I finally gave up on this. There are two many ambiguous cases, where one cannot decide whether something is a path/file name with a comma in it or it is a separator. I suspect MS-Project will quote strings somehow to solve these problems. I do not have the software here to test this.