# MS Project - How can I get the Unique ID of an External Dependency Task?

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-project

I'm working on a tool in c# that will look at dependencies of a task and then filter the MS Project file for those dependencies. It works great in a "regular" MS Project file but I can't figure out how to make it work in an Integrated Master Project file that contains linked source subprojects.

Here's an example of what I'm doing - In this example integrated project file I've tied the milestone "Preliminary Design Review 1" from the "SSI_Example 1" Project as the predecessor to the milestone "Preliminary Design Review 2" in the "SSI_Example 2" Project

[image: Multi-Project Example image]

What I want to be able to do is loop through the the Task Dependencies object of "Preliminary Design Review 2", and get all of the UIDs of the predecessor dependencies. I'm expecting the UID of the External Dependency.From to return either 6 or 8388614 (The UID values for Preliminary Design Review 1). Given either of those values, I can calculate either the source UID or the master project UID of the task.

However when I actually put this into code and loop through the Task Dependencies of "Preliminary Design Review 2" it returns 107 as the UID for the external predecessor. It seems like 107 is the UID of the "ghost task" that gets created in the source project

[image: Ghost Task Image]

Here's an example of the code:

```
private void TestGetPredessorUID(MSP.Task t)
    {
        var taskDependencyList = t.TaskDependencies.ToList(); //ToList is an extention I created method

        //Get only the Predecessor dependencies of the task
        //the GetUID method will always return the UID of the task as it is in the integrated file (source UID + source project seed value)
        taskDependencyList = taskDependencyList.Where(tDep => GetUID(tDep.To) == GetUID(t)).ToList();

        foreach (var dep in taskDependencyList)
        {
            /* If the dependency is an external dependency, dep.From it returns the UID of the "ghost task" not the UID of actual task, 
             even if we are inside the integrated "Master" Project */
            Debug.Print(dep.From.UniqueID.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**Bottom line**

Is it possible to get the "real" UID of an external dependency (either as it is in the source project or the master project) without parsing through the Task.Predecessors/Successors or Task.UniqueIDPredecessors/Successors string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the "real" UID of an external dependency without
> parsing through the Task.UniqueIDPredecessors/Successors string?

The native task unique ID is not exposed anywhere at the task level for the ghost task. However, parsing the UniqueIDPredecessors string can be done [using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11456932/need-regex-pattern-to-match-ms-project-predecessor-list).

This pattern will match most predecessor/successor strings:

`(((<>\\[^\\]+\\)+)|([A-Z]:|\\)\\([^\\]+\\)+)?\d+([FS]{2}([+-]\d+d)?)?(?=,|$)`

I suggest creating a new extension that uses this regex pattern to split up the UniqueIDPredecessors & UniqueIDSuccessors properties in order to get the native UID of the external tasks.

**Update regarding duration units & their labels**

The regex pattern shown above is looking for lead/lag time expressed in days. It can be modified to find lead/lag times expressed in other units (i.e. minutes, hours, weeks, months, and years) if needed.

Note that the duration unit *labels* can be formatted on a project-by-project basis from the Advanced tab of the Project Options dialog box:

[image: Project Options box]

The settings can be read and changed through code using properties such as [DayLabelDisplay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.daylabeldisplay) and [SpaceBeforeTimeLabels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.project.spacebeforetimelabels).

Before using a regex pattern to match durations in a predecessor string, take note of the user's current settings then change them to match what the regex is expecting and then reset the user's original settings at the end.

One final note: Durations can also be expressed as elapsed time which can be thought of calendar time rather than working time. For example, 9/1/2021 + 30ed = 10/1/2021 whereas 9/1/2021 + 30d = 10/12/2021. Elapsed durations are commonly found in lag times (e.g. a task can start after the concrete has cured). Therefore the regex pattern should include an optional 'e' before the lead/lag time unit.

Here is an untested regex pattern updated to include elapsed durations and all possible units:

`(((<>\\[^\\]+\\)+)|([A-Z]:|\\)\\([^\\]+\\)+)?\d+([FS]{2}([+-]\d+e?(min|hr|d|wk|mon|yr)?)?(?=,|$)`

Comment: Rachel, this is the case even if you are inside of the Master project file?

Comment: Yes. The UniqueIDPredecessors & UniqueIDSuccessors have the same format in the master and subprojects. You can parse these fields out to get the actual, native unique ID for the linked task.

Comment: Rachel, through some testing I've found that the regex pattern provided will not match if the the dependency has a lag and the word "days" is actually spelled out instead of just "d" (ex: 6FS+6 days vs 6FS+ 6d). Some versions of MS Project actually spell out the lag duration and put a space between the lag number and duration unit. In regards to different duration units, this pattern doesn't seem to work for lag types in minutes, hours, weeks, months, elapsed durations, or percentages (lag can be a percentage of the predecessor or successor task's duration). Can you help?

Comment: @KennyArnold I updated the answer to address these issues. I forgot to include the lag as a percentage; however, that should be easy to add to the regex pattern. Perhaps `(min|hr|d|wk|mon|yr|%)` would work.

Comment: ah I was getting confused because I was already changing the duration unit labels in the master project, but it wasn't changing in the UniqueID Predecessors/Successors string (it was still spelling out "days") but I realize now it's because I didn't change the duration unit label in the actual subproject file. I was thinking the string would always spell out the full word regardless of the label set by the user

Comment: I believe this pattern will work for all of the pred/succ strings regardless of user settings: `(((<>\\[^\\]+\\)+)|([A-Z]:|\\)\\([^\\]+\\)+)?\d+([FS]{2}([+-]\d(\s*)+e?(m|min|mins|minute|minutes|h|hr|hrs|hour|hours|d|dy|dys|day|days|w|wk|wks|week|weeks|mo|mon|mons|month|months|y|yr|yrs|year|years|%)?)?(?=,|$))?`